# Projection of $X \times Y$ is closed if $Y$ is compact

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, compactness, product-space

This question has already been answered, but I post this for correction of a false solution. Let $\pi_X:X \times Y \to X$ be the projection onto $X$. We wish to show that if $Y$ is compact, this is a closed map.

Let $F \subseteq X \times Y$ be closed. Then, $X \times Y \setminus F$ is open in the product space. Hence:

$$X \times Y  \setminus F = \bigcup_I U_i \times V_i$$

where $U_i, V_i$ open in $X,Y$ respectively for each $i \in I$, where $I$ is some index set.

I think it is true that:

$$X \times Y \setminus (U_i \times V_i) = \Big((X \setminus U_i) \times Y\Big) \cup \Big(X \times (Y\setminus V_i) \Big)$$

$$ \implies F = \bigcap_I \bigg(\Big((X \setminus U_i) \times Y\Big) \cup \Big(X \times (Y\setminus V_i) \Big) \bigg)$$

$$ \implies F = \bigcap_I \Big((X \setminus U_i) \times Y\Big) \cup \bigcap_I \Big(X \times (Y\setminus V_i) \Big)$$

If $\bigcup_I Y \setminus V_i \neq \emptyset$, $\pi_X(F) = X$ which is closed in $X$. Otherwise, $\pi_X(F) = \bigcap_I X \setminus U_i$, which is also closed in $X$. But the argument hasn't used compactness, so it must be incorrect. I think the issue must lie in my last two expressions for $F$ -- I am not sure my manipulation of sets is correct.

Comment: How do you get the last implication? intersection of sums is equal the sum of intersections?

Comment: Thank you. You are absolutely correct; it is wrong. Suppose I remove the last implication and consequent paragraph. Can the argument still be completed in this way, by reading off $\pi_X(F)$ from the correct expression? It is difficult for me to see any way to express $\pi_X(F)$.

Comment: Why you try to prove this way? $\pi_X(F)$ is a complement of the set $\{x|\forall_{y}(x,y)\in U\}$ where $U$ is a complement of $F$.

Comment: @Mateo Yes, that is better and I know that argument, but I was trying to see if this one could be made to work too.